# SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa'

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I tried to connect to Microsoft SQL Server Management with Laravel with **PHP V8.2.10**, and then I got this error message

> SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa' )

when I go to SQL Server log file it shows error like this

> login failed for user 'sa', Reason: password did not match that for the login provided)

Here's what I have config in .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=ip_address
DB_PORT=null
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD="password"
```

and here's what I have config in config/database.php file:

```
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', ''),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE','forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME','forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            // 'prefix_indexes' => true,
            // 'encrypt' => env('DB_ENCRYPT', 'yes'),
            // 'trust_server_certificate' => env('DB_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'true'),
        ],
```

Comment: *"Reason: password did not match that for the login provided"* The error is pretty specific here; what about the error don't you understand? Why is your application using the `sa` account anyway? Why have you not created it its *own* `LOGIN` with the minimal permissions it needs to do its task.

Comment: if i create another user will work? even if i input the correct password it still shows the error.

Comment: If the password is correct, you would not get that error in the logs.

Comment: For security it would be a lot better to use a different SQL user account, which only has the necessary privileges, rather than the administrator account

Comment: Does your actual password contain any special characters? Certain characters, such as `$` dollar signs, may need to be escaped with a backslash.

Comment: can you give me with example?